# Get attr when call function inside html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick, attr

I have function:

```
 function delMeh() {
                console.log('prolazi klik');
var did = $(this).attr('data-value');
$.ajax({
            url: "delTmeh.php",
            type: "POST",
            async: true, 
            data: { vrednostid:did}, //your form data to post goes here as a json object
            dataType: "html",
            success: function(data) {
            $('#tablemeh').dataTable().fnDestroy();
        drawMeh();   
            },
             error: function(data) {
             console.log(data);
             }
        });
}
```

and HTML:

```
<i data-value="32" onclick="delMeh();" class="fa fa-times delMeh"></i>
```

SO, on click I need to delete row 32 from database, but how I can get data-value of clicked element... 
I try with:`var did = $(this).attr('data-value');` inside delMeh() function but dont work.

How to get attr data-value of clicked element when call function like I need to do?

Comment: `onclick="delMeh(this);"`. Then it will work when you set an argument to function `delMeh`. However using inline events is highly discouraged.

Comment: ok, but I need to use it inline becouse I create html dinamicly and .on click and similar events dont work for me

Answer (score 2):

Why do u need the data value, when using a inline function click?
You could directly pass the value as a parameter to the function.

```js
    
    function delMeh(value) {
        // do your stuff
      }
```

```html
    <i onclick="delMeh(32);" class="fa fa-times delMeh"></i>
```

This would work good, but I seriously doubt the usage of `this` in a inline function call, as it could be used when a element's event is binded using jquery event listener.

Then you can use `$(this).data('value')`

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Send the element on the `onclick` method

`onclick="delMeh(this);"`

and receive the element on your function

```
function delMeh(element) {

      // than you can get the value with
      var did = $(element).attr('data-value');
      // or
      var did = $(element).data('value');

}
```

---

Or you could do it the jQuery way, by binding the on click handler on your html elements like this:

```
$(".delMeh").click(function() {
    // here you could use this
    var did = $(this).attr('data-value');
});
```

where you won't need to set the inline onclick attribute on each element.

Check this question to understand the difference between [.attr vs. .data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7261619/jquery-data-vs-attr).

Answer (score 1):

```js
function delMeh() {
   console.log('prolazi klik');
   var did = $(this).attr('data-value');
   alert(did);
}

$(".delMeh.fa.fa-times").click(delMeh);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<i data-value="32" class="fa fa-times delMeh">test</i>
```

This uses the more standard `addEventListener`. AddEventListener allows for multiple events of the same type and passes the this argument to the function. It also prevents the overwriting of the inline events.

Comment: I will try... so this is better than inline function call ? Why?

Comment: @dertdetg prevents overwriting by other (external) sources. Eg. you load a jQuery plugin that sets an inline onclick handler on all your italic elements, then your own click handler get's overwritten. With `addEventListener` or jQuery's event handlers you prevent this. Also these event setters pass a reference to the function of the element that owns the event (ergo the `this` keyword).

Comment: Not work, this code just call my function delMeh() ajax non-stop, and dont stoped

Comment: How is it invoked then?

Comment: The code works fine. You can trust me. It's about the implementation. Can I take a look at the full code somehow?

Comment: @dertdetg There is a loop. You call `drawMeh` inside the Ajax call and `drawMeh` calls `delMeh`

Comment: yes, I solve this problem, But now I cant put $(".delMeh").click(delMeh); on right place, I cant run it, ... Where I need to put this? I was try to put into document ready but dont work

Comment: You need to put this on the place where you know the datatable is done rendering and all delete row buttons are created.

Answer (score 0):

You really should avoid using inline event handlers with jQuery as others mention. The reason include getting new jQuery bubbling functionality and *not* separating the event registration code from the event handling code.

It sounds like your elements are created dynamically, which is probably why your previous attempt at using `.on` failed (mentioned in your comments). That also means none of the other suggestions will work as-is.

Instead use a single *delegated event handler*, attached to a non-changing ancestor element. `document` is the default if nothing else is closer/convenient. In your case the better element might be `$('#tablemeh').on(...`, but I would need to see a sample of your page's HTML.

A delegated event handler listens for the event (in this case `click`) to bubble up to the element, *then* it applies the jQuery selector. *Then* it calls your function only on the matching elements that caused the event. That means the elements only have to exist/match at event time.

Also, use `data` as a short-cut to fetch attributes with a `data-` prefix.

So instead of your existing code, just use something like this:

```
 $(document).on('click', '.delMeh', function(){
      var did = $(this).data('value');
      $.ajax({
        url: "delTmeh.php",
        type: "POST",
        async: true, 
        data: { vrednostid: did },
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(data) {
        $('#tablemeh').dataTable().fnDestroy();
    drawMeh();   
        },
         error: function(data) {
         console.log(data);
         }
    });
 });
```